# Tcl regexp cache with lists of RE

Tags: regex, performance, tcl

I read that [Tcl caches the last 30 regexp compiled and also that assigning a variable to the RE in string version will make Tcl attach the compiled RE to the variable the first time it is used](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986#pagetocc3d68533). But what I can't seem to find is if that compiled RE caching will still be done if the RE are contained in a list and iterated upon.

Basically, imagine I have this :

```
set REs {
    "RE 1"
    "RE 2"
    .
    .
    .
    "RE 39"
    "RE 40"
}

foreach re $REs {
    if { [regexp -nocase $re $line] } {
        AchieveWorldPeace $line
    }
}
```

Since those REs are used over and over and since I have more than 30 REs (and I don't want to recompile `Tcl` after changing the corresponding `#define` based solely on that script), the caching becomes important for the script to run at its fastest. **My question is therefore : in this example, would the regular expression be recompiled at each loop? If yes, is there a way to ensure caching when using lists of regular expressions?**

Basically, is there a way for the caching to be attached to the `Tcl_Object` pointed to by the list and not to the `Tcl_Object` pointed to by the iterator in the `foreach` ? (Note : that question might be wrong on multiple levels because I don't have any experience in terms of Tcl source code, but it's how I imagined the whole thing to be implemented.)

Please note that this question is more oriented on a better understanding of `Tcl` than on a specific code answer.

Also, I know I can do something like this :

```
set RE "(RE 1|RE 2| ... |RE 39|RE 40)"

if { [regexp -nocase $RE $line] } {
    AchieveWorldPeace $line
}
```

And, from my tests, I know that this speeds up my script by about a factor of two (which is not bad considering the script does a lot more). However, there is no way to tell easily which RE was matched when implemented this way, so it's not quite the same. (Not critical in my case, but just saying...)

Comment: As far as I can tell, you would have to change `#define NUM_REGEXPS` in the [source](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/tcl/tcl-5/tcl/generic/tclRegexp.c). I'm not sure if this can be overridden in a Tcl script, so maybe someone else knows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tcl uses two caches of RE compilations. One is the per-thread cache, and the other is in the `Tcl_Obj` internal representation of the RE. Since the values in a list retain their internal representations, the `foreach` of a list will keep them as well: your example code will be perfectly well cached with no need for further special action by you. Easy!

Comment: That is nice to hear. But how is it that my second example takes a lot less time than the first one?

Comment: The second example is a single call to regexp, while the first one are forty plus the foreach loop time :)